# Get SOQL result from multiple tables and use in APEX

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object

I have two custom objects ObjA and ObjB. ObjA.b is a LookUp field for ObjB. I have written following SOQL.

```
SELECT Id, b.Name FROM ObjA
```

This query gives correct results. Then I need to use these data in APEX code. But What is the return type of above query?

I know I can do as follows if there is only one object.

```
List<ObjA> obj_As = [SELECT Id, b FROM ObjA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type returned from a query is *always* defined by your `FROM` clause. You can sometimes assign to a singular object instead of a list when you *know* there is **exactly** one result. But the type would be the same. No other clause in your query matters. Only `FROM`.

Please note that the syntax for querying a parent field involves using the *relationship name*. For example, if you create a custom lookup named `Parent__c`, you would typically pull `Parent__r.Name`. If you use some arbitrary string like `b`, you are actually just using an alias on the query object itself.

Comment: But then I can not access `obj_As[0].b.Name`

Comment: Yes you can...why do you think you cannot?

Comment: Yeah. It's working...

Answer (score 0):

List obj_As = [SELECT Id, ObjA__r.b FROM ObjA]
you need to specify relationship between your object and fields for that you must use __r for relation in SOQL